# How to Integrate a Substrate Chain with MetaMask and Implement Specific Features?

Tags: substrate-node-template, evm, frontier

I am currently working on a project that involves creating a `Substrate chain` and I have several questions related to this:

**Integration with MetaMask:** I want to be able to connect my Substrate chain to MetaMask. How can I accomplish this?

**Deploying Smart Contracts in Solidity:** I'd like to give users of the network the ability to deploy smart contracts using Solidity. What are the steps that I need to follow?

**Transaction Fee Customization:** I am looking for a way to set custom transaction fees for different functions within my network. Is there a way to do this?

**Implementing ERC-721:** I plan to use ERC-721 technology in my project. How can I integrate this with my Substrate chain?

Lastly, I have come across the Frontier project, and I wonder if it might provide solutions to my questions. Has anyone used Frontier in this context and what has been your experience?

What I mean by this question is whether there will be a change in the way of coding in palettes or not? Or does it make our network compatible with Metamask and the implementation of Solidity codes?

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to Integrate the [Frontier](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier.git) into your `Substrate` Chain Frontier have `Pallet_evm` and `Pallet_ethereum` which provide EVM comaptibility to substrate for integrating the pallets you can follow this [tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-application-logic/add-a-pallet/) and For the `Metmask`support you need to integrate the `RPC's` into you substrate node and make changes to your `Services.rs` file,you can take reference from  [ChainX](https://github.com/chainx-org/ChainX.git) , [Reef-chain](https://github.com/reef-defi/reef-chain.git) & [Moonbeam](https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam).

For `Transaction Fee` Customization you can change [here](https://github1s.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/HEAD/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L460-L461) and customize it according to your requirement.

Comment: What I mean by this question is whether there will be a change in the way of coding in palettes or not? Or does it make our network compatible with Metamask and the implementation of Solidity codes?

Comment: There is no change  in coding of pallets. after the integration its make your network compatible with metamask and you can use remix ide and deploy EVM contracts on your chain.